# Nested If statement Excel - checking if value exists

Tags: excel, vlookup, nested-if

I have a spreadsheet with multiple row with varying data in the collumns eg:

```
Student NO       Book1   Book 2    Book 3   Book 4    Book 5
  X               12
  Y               13        12        23        23        32
```

What I want to do is a Lookup of that mark in another table to see if the book exists, and to come back with NA if the mark isn't in the other spreadsheet.

I have the following code, although if the book isn't in the bounds then it comes back as blank. :'( is there a way to make it N/A.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Q3,'Libary Books 21-06-13'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(Q3,'Libary Books 21-06-13'!$A:$B,2,FALSE))
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `""` in the `Value_if_true` part of your formula with `"NA"`.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Q3,'Libary Books 21-06-13'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)),"NA",VLOOKUP(Q3,'Libary Books 21-06-13'!$A:$B,2,FALSE))
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:**
The best way to understand these kinds of nested formulas is to make them as simple as possible so that you can make sure what is happening.

I set up two columns, `Book Name` in column A and `Nested If` in column B on a single sheet.

The formula in column B is

```
=IF(ISNA(A2), "", IF(A2="", "Doesn't Exist", A2))
```

I copied and pasted that formula to all rows. Here are the results:

```
Book Name              Nested If
The Sun Also Rises     The Sun Also Rises
                       Doesn't Exist
#N/A
```

You can use the formula above as your template.

Comment: I don't think I have fully explained: That is what I would ordinarily have done, except for the fact that I want if there to be NO value in Book 2 (or whichever) then for the end field to be blank, and then if the book doesn't exist for it to say "DOESN"T Exist'
Thanks for your quick reply :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you can detect the different conditions. If the vlookup fails, you'll get a #NA. If the vlookup doesn't fail, the book was found, and therefore exists. What is the difference between #NA and "Doesn't Exist"?

Comment: I was hoping for a nice clean sheet thats all, because at the moment it looks really messy with sometimes 20+ fields being put as N/A needlessly. 

If there is a value in the Book Name, then I want it to do the look-up, and then from there you get the N/A else you get nothing in the column.